# In Ruby how do I call a base class method from a different method in a derived class that overrides that same method?

Tags: ruby

If I have a base class with method 'a' and a derived class that reimplements method 'a', I can call Base.a from Derived.a by just calling `super`; how do I call the base class 'a' from a different derived class method?

```
class Base
  def a
    puts "hi, this is Base.a"
  end

end

class Derived < Base
  def a
    puts "hi, this is Derived.a"
  end

  def b
    # here is where I want to call Base.a
    Base.a  # this doesn't work
    
  end
end
```

Comment: Without further context this seems like a code smell. Can you add some explanation?

Comment: @Stefan, please clarify the smell? Closer to freshly-baked bread or a beached whale carcass?

Comment: @CarySwoveland more like a subtle burnt wood smell. Could be the neighbor having a barbecue or the roof being on fire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [Method#super_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method):

```
class Base
  def a
    puts "hi, this is Base.a"
  end
end
```

```
class Derived < Base
  def a
    puts "hi, this is Derived.a"
  end

  def b
    # here is where I want to call Base.a
    method(:a).super_method.call
  end
end
```

```
Derived.new.b
hi, this is Base.a
```

---

More generally, you could have arguments and/or a block.

```
class Base
  def c(x, &block)
    puts "ho, this is Base.c"
    block.call(3*x)
  end  
end
```

```
class Derived < Base
  def c(x, &block)
    puts "ho, this is Derived.c"
    block.call(x)
  end  

  def d(x, &block)
    method(:c).super_method.call(x, &block)
  end
end
```

```
Derived.new.d(5) { |x| puts "#{x} is a lot" }
ho, this is Base.c
15 is a lot
```

---

You could also do the following.

```
class A
  def a
    "A.a"
  end
end
```

```
class B < A
  def a
    "B.a"
  end
end
```

```
class C<B
  def a
    "C.a"
  end
```

```
  def test
    method(:a).super_method.super_method.call
  end
end
```

```
C.new.test
  #=> "A.a"
```

Comment: or `A.instance_method(:a).bind_call(self)` if class and method name are known / given.

Comment: @Stefan, good suggestion. More generally, it appears you could write `self.class.superclass.instance_method(:a).bind_call(self)`. I thought about `self.class.superclass.instance_method(:a)` but didn't know how to do the binding, and was unaware of `bind_call`. Consider posting your suggestion as an answer and explain bindings.

Answer (score 6):

`alias_method` can do it:

> Makes new_name a new copy of the method old_name. This can be used to retain access to methods that are overridden.

*https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/module#method-i-alias_method*

```rb
class Base
  def a
    puts "hi, this is Base.a"
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  alias_method :base_a, :a

  def a
    puts "hi, this is Derived.a"
  end

  def b
    base_a
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Derived.new.b
hi, this is Base.a
>> Derived.new.a
hi, this is Derived.a
```

Comment: This seems the simplest solution. One sees `alias` and `alias_method` less often since `prepend` came onto the scene, but they still have their uses, as you have shown.